# TypeScript - Namespace/Scope variable updates

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm getting some settings from a local JSON file. The `console.log` inside the function correctly logs the object, but the second after the function returns `undefined`, so the variable isn't being updated?

Also, within `testNameSpace`, `this` returns `window`, why?

```
namespace testNameSpace {

    let settings: any;

    function dtJSONLoad() {
        let xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', './js/file.json', true);
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4) {
                let response = xobj.responseText;
                settings = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(settings);
            }
        };
        xobj.send(null);
    }

    dtJSONLoad();
    console.log(settings);

}
```

*console logs 'undefined'*

*console logs returned object'*

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's related to being async. Set to false it updates correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing two of the most common issues that are being asked about in SO (at least the ones that are tagged with `TypeScript`).

The first is that you are making an async operation and so when you are doing this:

```
dtJSONLoad();
console.log(settings);
```

The `console.log` part is being executed **before** the `dtJSONLoad` has finished, and so the `settings` variable is undefined.
Your 2nd `console.log` happens when the async operation completes which is why you see the value.

The 2nd issue is the scope of `this`:
You are assigning a function to the `xobj.onreadystatechange` property, this function isn't bound to the current `this` so when it is executed the `this` is referencing the `Window` object.
You have two options here:

(1) Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which saves the current scope of `this`:

```
xobj.onreadystatechange =  () => {
    // ...
};
```

(2) Use the F[unction.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
xobj.onreadystatechange =  function () {
    // ...
}.bind(this);
```

---

#### Edit

A namespace doesn't have `this`, and that's because of how it's being compiled into javascript.
For example, this:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    console.log(this); // Error: 'this' cannot be referenced in a module or namespace body
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var mynamespace;
(function (mynamespace) {
    console.log(this);
})(mynamespace || (mynamespace = {}));
```

Which is equivalent of doing:

```
function fn() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

In both cases `this` is referencing the `Window` object.

If you do this however:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    export function fn() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

mynamespace.fn();
```

It will print: `Object {}` which is right, and that's because the `fn` function resides inside `mynamespace`.
And the js result looks like this:

```
var mynamespace;
(function (mynamespace) {
    function fn() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    mynamespace.fn = fn;
})(mynamespace || (mynamespace = {}));
```

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. When I `console.log(this);` inside `namespace testNameSpace` it returns `window` as well though, why is this?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 0):

The Data is not there the first time you log it.

The Second time is in the callback, when the data arrived, the fist time just the second after the request started.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that's not the case. If I comment out the console.log after the function, the object returns. If I comment out the one inside the function,only undefined is returned. I don't why they are logging in that order, though.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying @PaulRedmond. Pls add some string to your logs to identify them.